# Can someone explain what "Exotics Trade Capture" capture means in layman's terms?

Tags: trade, exotics

I am trying to find out what *Exotics Trade Capture* entails. I can't find anything on Google that isn't a job posting, which is where I saw this term.

Say you did this for a living, how would you explain it to someone that didn't know anything about it?

What references on the internet would you point them to find out more information about it?

Comment: Do you have a reference or a context for this term?

Comment: I think you are confused. The only references I've seen to this term on google show it as two separate terms, exotics, and trade capture. Do you have a reference showing it as a single term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wilmott](http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=3&threadid=86072):

> Trade capture is the process of booking (or capturing) the trade into
>   the systems used within a financial organisation. This may sometimes have to happen multiple times
>   depending on the complexity of the trades and the ability of the
>   systems to be able to capture the economic, non-economic and static
>   details surrounding the deal.
>
> The ideal situation is to STP (Straight through process) these deals
>   from the point of execution through to all of the banks systems with
>   no manual touch points. Obviously the more vanilla the product, and
>   the greater the volume, the more automated it will be. FX and cash
>   equity for example, is highly automated, with only "exceptions"
>   manually handled. Listed equity derivative trading is now heavily
>   automated/ STP, although not entirely. One of the expected outcomes of
>   increased regulation/ standardisation of credit/rate trades will be
>   not only to force them onto clearing houses and exchanges, but also to
>   increase the opportunity for STPing these deals into the risk systems
>   of the financial institutions. In fact, it will almost certainly be
>   expected and required.

And from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_derivatives):

> Exotic derivatives, in finance, refer to derivative instruments which
>   have features making them more complex than commonly traded,
>   "vanilla", products, usually relating to determination of payoff.
>   The category may also include derivatives with a non-standard subject
>   matter (i.e. underlying), developed for a particular client or a
>   particular market.
>
> Note that the term has no precise meaning: the definition is dependent
>   on time and place. Interest rate- and currency-swaps were exotic when
>   they first appeared in the 1980s, but are now standard financial
>   tools. Similarly, proprietary products originally developed by
>   merchant banks or other financial institutions to meet the needs of
>   particular clients may in time diffuse more widely into the market.

"Exotics trade capture" would presumably mean trade capture of exotics.

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I was looking for, the first part was what I was having a hard time pinning down!